# check box always in unchecked mode after page reload

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

forms.py

```
Date_Format = (
    ('0', ' dd / mm / yyyy'),
    ('1', 'mm / dd / yyyy'),
)

Time_Format = (
    ('0', ' 12 hour AM / PM '),
    ('1', ' 24 hour '),
)

class SettingsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    date_format = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(), choices=Date_Format)
    time_format = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(), choices=Time_Format)
    class Meta:
        model = Settings
        fields = ['date_format','time_format']
```

views.py

```
def date_format(request):
  #  settingsForm = SettingsForm({'user':request.user}) 
    settings = Settings.objects.get(user=2)
    settingsForm = SettingsForm(instance=settings) 
  #  dateformatForm = DateFormatForm()   
   # timeformatForm = TimeFormatForm()
    settingsForm = SettingsForm()
    if request.method =='POST':
      #  dateformatForm = DateFormatForm(request.POST)
      #  timeformatForm = TimeFormatForm(request.POST)
        settingsForm = SettingsForm(request.POST,instance=settings)
        if (settingsForm.is_valid()):  
            settings=settingsForm.save()
       #     timeformatForm.save()
            return redirect('/member/follow-up/') 


    return render_to_response( 'incident/date_format.html',
                  {
                   'about_menu': True,
                   'SettingsForm':settingsForm,

                 },
                 context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

models.py

```
class Settings(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    date_format = models.CharField('Date format', max_length=100)
    time_format = models.CharField('Time format', max_length=100)
```

template is

```
<form action="/member/date-format/" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
{{ SettingsForm.date_format }}
{{ SettingsForm.time_format }}
</form>
```

I am using models form here to store the form value in database.

If i select the radio button choice.the corresponding values are saving in database.But the checked radio button will uncheck if the page is reloaded.I don't know what logic to use to do this.

Moreover,is any way to save the values of radio button in template without using modelsForm.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view:

```
def date_format(request):
  #  settingsForm = SettingsForm({'user':request.user}) 
    settings = Settings.objects.get(user=2)
    settingsForm = SettingsForm(instance=settings) 
  #  dateformatForm = DateFormatForm()   
   # timeformatForm = TimeFormatForm()
    settingsForm = SettingsForm()
    ....
```

You are resetting the `settingsForm` with empty form, which will show the form without any values from instance `settings`. You may want to remove that line.